# Jsoup closes <p> tag at the wrong point

Tags: html, jsoup, html-parsing, paragraph

For some reason Jsoup is incorrectly parsing an html document, specifically a paragraph that contains a group of paragraph in a table.

Input:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <p>
                <p> Title <br/> New</p>
                <p> Content new </p>
             </p>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

After parsing:

```
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
            <p> </p>
            <p> Title <br> New</p>
            <p> Content new </p>
            <p></p>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Do you know what may be causing this and how I can solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct parsing behaviour. Because `<p>` elements are block-level elements, they cannot be nested inside other `<p>` elements.

[According to the MDN documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

> Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>` tag.

A possible solution is using another element such as a `<section>` or `<div>`. For example:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <div>
                <p> Title <br/> New</p>
                <p> Content new </p>
             </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is there a way of not closing them? I'm parsing an html that wasn't created by me and I'm forced to parse it.

Comment: @CésarCastroAroche I edited my answer with an example solution. The original code doesn't meet W3C guidelines, so you cannot expect it to consistently be parsed correctly.

Comment: If you have to parse it anyway use xmlParser `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());` to skip HTML valdation.